# Angular: What is the better way to optimize speed (ng-directives or $watch)?

Tags: angularjs

I have a several input fields and I have to do different calculating manipulations. I'm wondering what is the better way to implement this using $watch or standard angular directives.

Example:

```js
$scope.calculate = function(argument) {
// do something
}

$watch('item', fucntion(){
// do something       
       
})
```

```html
<div> 
 <input type="text" ng-model="item.one" ng-keyup="calculate(item)">
 <input type="text" ng-model="item.two" ng-keyup="calculate(item)">
 <input type="text" ng-model="item.three" ng-keyup="calculate(item)">

</div>
```

As I know AngularJs sets up a watcher for every directive, so in this situation I have 3 watchers for `ng-keyup="calculate(item)"`, as I understand it's better to use one `$watch` in this case, but what if my `item` is nested: $scope.container.things.item

How it will be affect on speed performance and what is best practice to make such a manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply set up watches, when/how will they trigger? what will trigger the digest loop that evaluates those watches?

It's those directives. So it's not a question about performance, there is actually only one option. You need to use the directives to trigger digest loop based on user interaction.